# Parent Element doesn't detect child overflow

Tags: css

I have a `<div>` with several lists.

The lists again contains several `<div>` elements inside it. I have an element deep inside with a text that overflows, how to scroll the parent view horizintally in this case?

[image]

In the code below, the `span` element overflows the text and I want the entire list to scroll
[image]

Comment: Are you going to provide code..?

Comment: There is a lot of code. what you exactly need? I just need to know how the parent element detects that it's child element has text which is overflowing.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve